# Populate Camel route removeHeaders pattern attribute with property

Tags: spring, apache-camel, properties-file

I have a Camel route defined in xml DSL with a `<removeHeaders>` element where I specify a regex pattern e.g.`<removeHeaders pattern="*"/>` (pattern is simplified for brevity). I want to move the pattern string out of the xml and into a properties file and read the string in via the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer mechanism like `<removeHeaders pattern="${removeHeadersPattern}"/>` since I use this same pattern string for multiple routes. However, the attribute value is being treated as a literal string instead of getting replaced. Is there a way to make this work? Maybe I'm just missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/properties.html) for using properties in Camel. As per my understanding, we use properties with

- `${property_name}` place holder if it is used outside camel context.
- `{{property_name}}` within camel context.

Also, note that, beginning from Camel 2.9 we have provision to change these place holders using `prefixToken` and `suffixToken` paramters while loading properties.